# Creating DbContext with unity failing with additional ctr

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unity-container

I have custom DbContext which inherits from IdentityDbContext. Class looks like this:

```
public class ReaderContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    //DbSets

    public ReaderContext() 
        : base("name=ReaderDb")
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<ReaderContext>(null);
        Database.Initialize(true);
    }
 }
```

And when DbContext looks like this, code creating Repository (which is using ReaderContext) works fine:

```
container.RegisterType<IRepository, CustomRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
var repo = container.Resolve<IRepository>();
```

When I add another constructor (not removing existing one!) to ReaderContext, creating CustomRepository not works any more in UnityContainer.

```
    public ReaderContext(DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, true)
    {

    }
```

I need to have it that way, so I can moq context with Effort. I'm using Unity container. Exception I'm having:

> 2017-08-07 19:02:57.9256 : Exception :
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type =
>   "DataAccess.Database.Repositores.IRepository", name =
>   "(none)". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The current type,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnection, is an abstract class and cannot be
>   constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
>   ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving
>   DataAccess.Database.Repositores.CustomRepository,(none)
>   (mapped from
>   DataAccess.Database.Repositores.IRepository, (none))
>   Resolving parameter "context" of constructor
>   DataAccess.Database.Repositores.CustomRepository(DataAccess.Database.ReaderContext
>   context)
>       Resolving DataAccess.Database.ReaderContext,(none)
>       Resolving parameter "connection" of constructor DataAccess.Database.ReaderContext(System.Data.Common.DbConnection
>   connection)
>         Resolving System.Data.Common.DbConnection,(none)  ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The current type,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnection, is an abstract class and cannot be
>   constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Why adding new constructors break unity configuration? Also, I tried set unity from scratch but coudn't make it work. Probably I don't know how unity works, so any tips are welcome :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default Unity will select the constructor with the greatest number of parameters.  So, initially the parameterless constructor was used and everything was fine.

However, when you added the `ReaderContext(DbConnection connection)` constructor that constructor was now the constructor with the greatest number of arguments so Unity chose to use it.  For that constructor, Unity saw it needed a `DbConnection` but, as the exception message indicates, `DbConnection` is abstract so Unity could not instantiate it and there was no type mapping from the abstract `DbConnection` to a concrete non-abstract class that Unity could instantiate.

The solution is to explicitly tell Unity what you want it to do.  If you want to use the parameterless constructor you would do it by providing an `InjectionConstructor` with no arguments:

```
container.RegisterType<ReaderContext>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

If you wanted to use the `DbConnection` constructor you would either have to explicitly configure Unity with how to construct a `ReaderContext` or configure Unity with how to resolve the abstract `DbConnection`.  I would typically use the latter approach and configure the mappings and let Unity build the object graph:

```
container.RegisterType<DbConnection, SqlConnection>(
   new InjectionFactory(c => new SqlConnection("connectionString")));
```

Comment: Too bad I can't upvote more, great answer. "By default Unity will select the constructor with the greatest number of parameters." Thanks a lot